# Synchronize Method, can I use it to not main thread?

Tags: delphi, thread-synchronization

I rarely use threads and I have question about this class:

```
unit ExpectingThread;

interface

uses
    System.Classes;

type
    TExpectingThread = class(TThread)
    private
        _timeoutMs: Integer;
        _buff: string;
        _patterns: TArray<string>;
        _result: Integer;
        function Timeouted(startTime: Cardinal): Boolean;
        function ExpectedDetected: Boolean;

    protected
        procedure Execute; override;
    public
        constructor Create(patterns: TArray<string>; buff: string; timeoutMs: Integer);
        //this method is called from other NOT MAIN thread
        procedure BuffUpdate(text: string);
    end;

implementation

uses
    Winapi.Windows,
    System.RegularExpressions;

{ TExpectingThread }

constructor TExpectingThread.Create(patterns: TArray<string>; buff: string; timeoutMs: Integer);
begin
    _patterns := patterns;
    _timeoutMs := timeoutMs;
    _buff := buff;
end;

//this method is called from other NOT MAIN thread
procedure TExpectingThread.BuffUpdate(text: string);
begin
    // lock
    TThread.Synchronize(Self, procedure
        begin
            _buff := _buff + text;
        end);
    // unlock
end;

procedure TExpectingThread.Execute;
var
    startTime: Cardinal;
begin
    inherited;

    startTime := GetTickCount;
    while true do
    begin
        if Timeouted(startTime) then
        begin
            Self.ReturnValue := 0; // timeouted
            Exit;
        end;

        if ExpectedDetected then
        begin
            Self.ReturnValue := 1; // found
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
end;

function TExpectingThread.ExpectedDetected: Boolean;
var
    regex: TRegEx;
    i: Integer;
begin
    // lock
    result := 0;
    for i := 0 to High(_patterns) do
    begin
        regex.Create(_patterns[i]);
        if regex.IsMatch(_buff) then
        begin
            _result := i;
            Exit(true);
        end;
    end;
    // unlock
end;

function TExpectingThread.Timeouted(startTime: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
    currentTime: Cardinal;
begin
    currentTime := GetTickCount;
    result := currentTime - startTime > _timeoutMs;
end;

end.
```

Thread has to cheacking if any pattern is match to buffer over timeout. But other thread(NOT MAIN) can change buffer by using BuffUpdate method. Did I use Synchronization method correctly?

Comment: `Synchronize` is intended *only* for the *main* thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Synchronize()` is specifically designed to work with the main UI thread.  You *can* use it for inter-thread syncing, however ALL threads involved would have to use it. In your example, only the thread(s) that write to `_buff` are using it, but the thread that reads from `_buff` is not.  So that is a hole in your logic.

That being said, if the main UI thread does not need to touch your data, then `Synchronize()` is not the best solution to use. You can just wrap the data access with a synchronization object instead, like a `TCriticalSection`, `TMutex`, `TEvent`, `TMREWSync`, `Sytem.TMonitor`, etc.  For example:

```
unit ExpectingThread;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SyncObjs;

type
  TExpectingThread = class(TThread)
    private
      _timeoutMs: Integer;
      _buff: string;
      _buffLock: TCriticalSection;
      _buffChanged: Boolean;
      _patterns: TArray<string>;
      _result: Integer;
      function Timeouted(startTime: Cardinal): Boolean;
      function ExpectedDetected: Boolean;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    public
      constructor Create(patterns: TArray<string>; buff: string; timeoutMs: Integer);
      destructor Destroy; override;
      //this method is called from other NOT MAIN thread
      procedure BuffUpdate(text: string);
    end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.RegularExpressions;

{ TExpectingThread }

constructor TExpectingThread.Create(patterns: TArray<string>; buff: string; timeoutMs: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  _buffLock := TCriticalSection.Create;
  _patterns := patterns;
  _timeoutMs := timeoutMs;
  _buff := buff;
  _buffChanged := True;
end;

destructor TExpectingThread.Destroy;
begin
  _buffLock.Free;
  inherited;
end;

//this method is called from other NOT MAIN thread
procedure TExpectingThread.BuffUpdate(text: string);
begin
  _buffLock.Enter;
  try
    _buff := _buff + text;
    _buffChanged := True;
  finally
    _buffLock.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TExpectingThread.Execute;
var
  startTime: DWORD;
begin
  startTime := GetTickCount;
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    if Timeouted(startTime) then
    begin
      Self.ReturnValue := 0; // timeouted
      Exit;
    end;
    if ExpectedDetected then
    begin
      Self.ReturnValue := 1; // found
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TExpectingThread.ExpectedDetected: Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
  buff: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  _buffLock.Enter;
  try
    If not _buffChanged then Exit;
    buff := _buff;
    UniqueStr(buff);
    _buffChanged := False;
  finally
    _buffLock.Leave;
  end;
  for i := Low(_patterns) to High(_patterns) do
  begin
    if TRegEx.IsMatch(buff, _patterns[i]) then
    begin
      _result := i;
      Exit(True);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TExpectingThread.Timeouted(startTime: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  currentTime: DWORD;
begin
  currentTime := GetTickCount;
  result := currentTime - startTime > _timeoutMs;
end;

end.
```